# String must be exactly one character long Error in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to resolve this Error String Must be exactly one character long . 
i am sharing this function please look into this and resolve this issue .

i am highlighting line you can see this line . And how to solve this issue if can we convert char to string or something else.

Function

```
public DataTable mlogin(string username, string password)
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Real"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    password = Cryptographer.Encrypt(password);
    con.Open();

    if ( char.IsNumber( Convert.ToChar(username)))   //String must be exactly one character long
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select MD.MembershipID, MembershipName, address, ISNULL(FD.FileID,'') as FileID,ISNULL(Sec.SectorName, '') as SectorName, ISNULL(I.PlotNo, '') as PlotNo, MD.ClientPic from MemberMaster MM " +
            " inner join MembersDetail MD on MD.MemberShipID = MM.MemberShipID and MD.Srno = 1 " +
            " inner join MasterFileDetail FD on FD.MembershipID = MM.MemberShipID and FD.IsOwner = 1 and FD.IsTransfered = 1 " +
            " inner join MasterFile FM on FM.FileID = FD.FileID and FM.Cancel = 0 " +
            " inner join Sectors Sec on Sec.Phase_ID = FM.PhaseId and Sec.Sector_ID = FM.Sector_ID " +
            " inner join PlotsInventory I on I.Phase_ID = FM.PhaseId and I.Plot_ID = FM.Plot_ID " +
            " where MM.MemberShipID = '" + username + "' and MM.IsApproved = 1 and RTRIM(MM.LoginPwd) = '" + password + "' and MM.IsActive = 1 " +
            " order by FD.FileID", con);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select User_Id, User_Name,User_Type, Group_Id from BriskSecurity.dbo.Users where User_Login='" + username + "' and User_password='" + password + "' ", con);
    }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MembershipID",username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginPwd", password);
        DataTable mDT_User = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(mDT_User);
        con.Close();
        return mDT_User;

    }
```

Comment: Think about it, you're trying to convert a string to a single char. How would that work unless the string _is_ composed of a single char? I couldn't type convert "John" to a char, for example. Also, I could login as any user I like without a password using your current login SQL query (you should use SQL parameters).

Comment: if i have not Convert.ToChar(username) then error show string not convert to chart.

Comment: What you're doing is fundamentally wrong anyway. You really want `Convert.ToInt32(`, I think.

Comment: If you want to verify that "username" contains only number, you can use something like that: username.All(c => char.IsNumber(c));

Comment: `Convert.ToChar(username)` converts the first character to Unicode If You are expecting only one length string first check the length of the string and then try what you are trying to do

Comment: Awesome strelnikov-lev Problem Solve.

Answer (score 6):

What you're doing is fundamentally wrong.

Consider the username "John". Can you convert a 4 character string into a single char? No. You can't use this to validate if the whole username is a number.

Instead, you have two options:

(1) Validate that each char of the username is numeric:

```
if (username.All(c => char.IsNumber(c)))
{
```

(2) Parse it to a number (assuming it can be expressed as a number and leading zeroes aren't important)

```
if (int.TryParse(username, out var usernameAsInt))
{
```

---

Next, I recommend looking at parameterized SQL queries.

Imagine the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'"
```

What happens if my username is `' OR username = 'administrator'; --`? The query becomes this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '' OR username = 'administrator'; -- ' AND password = ''
```

Everything after the -- becomes a comment. You can learn more about parameterizing SQL queries [here](https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06).

Comment: +1 John, you pointed out the important issue in code which is SQL injection, even though earlier comment solved the issue.